# branching a git repository

Tags: github, branch

I have been given access to a git repository. I would like to create a new branch to the existing code. I am unable to find proper steps online to do this process. I believe i should first setup the master in git bash and then create a branch. If anyone can give me the sequence of steps to be followed, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is, creating the clone of the remote branch

```
 git clone <git repo> <folder_name>
```

example:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/abc my2.6
```

change directory to the newly formed directory ie my2.6

```
$ cd my2.6
```

Creating a new branch

```
git branch <branch name>

$ git branch my2.6.14
```

Go to new branch:

```
git checkout <branch name>
```

example:

```
$ git checkout my2.6.14
```

Answer (score 0):

The git pro book is a great source to find information and learning about git: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging.

First make sure you have cloned the git repository using git clone command. After that you can check the current branch with this command: git branch

You can create new branch using this command: git checkout -b mybranch